# iOS 4.3 Simulator Localization.strings working in French, but not English

Tags: ios, localization, ios-simulator

I have just started working on localization of this application. Starting with three tab bar button titles, I have Localization.strings files like these:

```
// English

// Tab Bar Controller Buttons
"Settings_Tab_Title" = "Settings";
"Results_Tab_Title"  = "Results";
"Map_Tab_Title"      = "Map";
```

and

```
// French

// Tab Bar Controller Buttons
"Settings_Tab_Title" = "Paramétres";
"Results_Tab_Title"  = "Résultats";
"Map_Tab_Title"      = "Plan";
```

When I change the device language to French, the proper button names show up. When I change the device language to English, the keys are showing instead of the values or contents.

This problem doesn't occur in the iOS 5 simulator or on an iOS 5 iphone. I don't have an iOS 4.3 device to test it on.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Now which one was it that solved it?

Comment: See my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775206/difficulty-localizing-xib-files This shows how I have it organized. I'm not sure what the original problem was, but basically I removed the items from the project and re-inserted them with the project directories organized as shown in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should occur on the 4.3 simulator too.

Are your files for the english texts in the directory en.lproj? Is the directory added to your project?

Do you have an entry `en` in the `Localization native development region` in your target info settings?

Answer (score 3):

File name could be wrong !!

```
Localization.strings
```

**must be**

```
Localizable.strings
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. You just saved my day.