# localizable.string does not work with simulator in iOS 8

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, multilingual, localizable.strings

I have a major problem with the localization of my app.

Since I updated Xcode to version  6.1.1 (6A2008a) with the new simulator iOS 8.1, I found that the iOS 8.1 simulator no longer works with Localizable.string.

When I turn the stimulator with the version of iOS 7.1 my app works fine and the language changes according to the setting made on the device. Why does this problem occur on 8.1?

Thanks

Comment: You have read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194911/localizable-strings-not-working-in-ios ?

Comment: Thanks Thomas,
I have carefully read, but the problem seems to be this.

I tried deleting and clean iPhone simulator and then build it again. But it does not work.

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058499/xcode-5-ios-7-localization-not-working-in-simulator I'm sorry, but I stopped IOS development so I can't really help.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything Thomas.
I have tried to do everything that I've read the responses to the forums you gave me turned but still have the same problems with the simulator iOS8.1 (Other simulators of older versions work fine). I hope that other people will respond to this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Xcode 6.1 release notes, this is a known bug in iOS 8.1 simulator runtime.  Please try iOS 8.2 beta in Xcode 6.2 beta, which contains the fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I hope that after upgrading to xcode 6.2 beta these problems disappear.
I think, however, turns rightly on a real device with iOS 8.1

In the meantime, I wish you all happy holidays christmas :)

Claudio